# Need tool for graphical projecting database which has option to generate CREATE scripts for different databases

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Can someone suggests me tool for graphical projecting database which has option to generate CREATE scripts for different databases ?

Comment: What's a "graphical projecting database"?

Comment: something like in Mysqlworkbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html). (It is free, too.)